# Time Arguments is no longer supported

Tags: r, shiny, gtrendsr

i have a problem using the gtrendsR package. When creating an example Shiny APP I always get the error:

Error in gtrends: unused arguments (start_date = start_date(), end_date = end_date())

The start and end date no longer exist in the current package.  Currently, start and end times only need to be specified as follows:

Time span between two dates (ex.: "2010-01-01 2010-04-03")

How can I change the function?

Many thanks for your help.

The complete code looks like this:

server.R:

```
    # Load libraries ====
if(!require(shiny)){
    install.packages('shiny')
      }
if(!require(gtrendsR)){
    install.packages('gtrendsR')
      }
if(!require(reshape2)){
    install.packages('reshape2')
      }
if(!require(ggplot2)){
    install.packages('ggplot2')
      }

library(shiny)
library(gtrendsR)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data(countries)

# Start shiny application

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



  out <- reactive({
    if(length(input$terms)>0){

      unlist(strsplit(input$terms,","))
    }
  })

  start_date<-reactive({

    if(input$period=="2004-present"){as.Date("2004-01-01")}

    else if (input$period=="Past90Days"){as.Date(Sys.time())-90}

    else if (input$period=="Past12Months"){
      m=as.POSIXlt(as.Date(Sys.time()))
      m$year=m$year-1
      m}

    else if (input$period=="2011"){as.Date("2011-01-01")}
    else if (input$period=="2012"){as.Date("2012-01-01")}
    else if (input$period=="2013"){as.Date("2013-01-01")}
    else if (input$period=="2014"){as.Date("2014-01-01")}
    else if (input$period=="2015"){as.Date("2015-01-01")}



  })


  end_date<-reactive({

    if(input$period %in% c("2004-present",
                           "Past90Days","Past12Months"))
                 {
      as.Date(Sys.time())}

    else if (input$period=="2011"){as.Date("2011-12-31")}
    else if (input$period=="2012"){as.Date("2012-12-31")}
    else if (input$period=="2013"){as.Date("2013-12-31")}
    else if (input$period=="2014"){as.Date("2014-12-31")}
    else if (input$period=="2015"){as.Date(Sys.time())} 

    })

geo<-reactive({
  if(input$geography=="Worldwide"){""}

  else{

    countries$CODE[countries$COUNTRY==input$geography]
  }

})

  data<-reactive({
    if(length(out()>0))
    {

      out2<-gtrends(query=out(),start_date=start_date(),end_date=end_date(),geo=geo())

    }

  })




  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    if(length(out()>0)){
      z=data()
      trend=z$trend

      if("end"%in%names(trend)==T)
                           {
      trend=select(trend,-end)}

      trend <- melt(trend, id='start')

      ggplot(trend, aes(start,value, color=variable)) + geom_line()+ggtitle("Interest over time")+
        ylab("Relative Trend")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18,colour="black"))+
        xlab('')+theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour="#00007A",size=14,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=1),
                       axis.text.y = element_text(colour="darkred",size=14,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0),
                       axis.text.x = element_text(colour="darkred",size=14,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0))+
        theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=15, 
                                          face="bold"))+
        theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="blue", size=14, 
                                         face="bold"))

    }

  })


 corr<-reactive({

   if(input$corr==T & length(out()>1)){

     z=data()
     trend=z$trend
     trend=trend[,3:ncol(trend)]
     cor(trend)

   }
 }) 


 output$myplot3 <- renderPlot({
   if(length(corr()>0)){
     data=corr()

     qplot(x=Var1, y=Var2, data=melt(cor(data)), fill=value, geom="tile")+
       ggtitle('Correlation Matrix')+theme(axis.title.y =element_blank(),axis.title.x =element_blank(),
                                           axis.text.y = element_text(colour="darkred",size=14,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0),
                                           axis.text.x = element_text(colour="darkred",size=14,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0))+
       theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
       theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=14))+scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-1, 1),low="skyblue", high="blue")+
       theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20,colour="black"))
   }
 })


  output$myplot2 <- renderPlot({
    if(length(out()>0)){
      data=data()


      z=data$searches
      rr=data$regions

      for (i in 1:length(z)){
        n=z[i]
        n=as.data.frame(n)
        names(n)=c("searches","hits")
        n$searches <- factor(n$searches, levels = n$searches[order(n$hits,decreasing =T)])

        colors=c("orange","skyblue","#999966")

        col=sample(c(1,2,3),1,replace=T)

        x11()

        print(ggplot(n, aes(searches,hits))+  
                geom_bar(stat='identity',fill=colors[col],color='black')+
                ggtitle(data$headers[2+2*length(z)+i])+ylab('Hits')+
                theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18,colour="blue"))+
                theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_text(colour="blue",size=14),axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=14,angle=60,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"))


        )


        if(geo()=='')
        {
        x11()


        regions = as.data.frame(rr)[c(1,i+1)]

        names(regions)=c('region','hits')

        regions$region[regions$region=="United States"] = "USA"

        world_map = map_data("world")

        world_map =merge(world_map, regions, by="region",all.x = TRUE)

        world_map = world_map[order(world_map$group, world_map$order),]

        g=ggplot(world_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
          geom_polygon(aes(fill=hits), color="gray70") 

        print(g+theme(axis.text.y   = element_blank(),
                      axis.text.x   = element_blank(),
                      axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
                      axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
                scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "blue", guide = "colorbar",na.value="white")+ggtitle(data$headers[2+2*length(z)+i])+ylab('Hits')+
                theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
                      legend.title = element_text(size = 12, colour = "blue"),
                      legend.title.align=0.3,legend.text = element_text(size = 10))+
                theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray70", fill=NA, size=0.5))
        )
        }
      }

    }

  }) 

  })
```

And ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="By Fish"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    br(),


    h6(" Search Term(s)",style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:150%"),

    helpText("Give one or more terms that you want R to retrieve data from the Google Trends API.
             Use comma to separate terms", style="text-align:center"),

    textInput('terms',''),


    selectInput("geography", 
label = tags$h4(strong(em("Geography")),style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:150%"),
                choices = c("Worldwide"),
                selected = "Worldwide"),           
            selectInput("period", 
                label = tags$h4(strong(em("Time Period")),style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:150%"),
                choices = c("2004-present",
                            "Past30Days",
                            "Past90Days",
                            "Past12Months",
                            "2011",
                            "2012",
                            "2013",
                            "2014",
                            "2015"
                ),
                selected = "2004-present"),

    checkboxInput("corr", 
                  label = strong("Correlation",style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:150%")),
    br(),

    tags$h1(submitButton("Update!"),style="text-align:center"),
    helpText("To get results, click the 'Update!' button",style="text-align:center"),

    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br()



    ),


  #####
  ##  Main Panel
  #### help ====        
  dashboardBody(    
    fluidRow(
      br(),
      h5(em(strong("Google Trends Analytics", style="color:darkblue;font-size:210%")),align = "center"),

      plotOutput("myplot"),
      br(),
      plotOutput("myplot3"),
      plotOutput("myplot2")


    )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is you are not using `gtrends()` in the right way probably the code was written for an older version of the package.

Please change your code like this.

`out2<- gtrends(keyword = out(),
                time = paste0(start_date()," ",end_date()),
                geo=geo())`

Please note even after that your code isn't running successfully because again the way the function result is handled in your code is different from what it actually returns so those need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had that but after that the next error came immediately. Probably that's what you meant. Warning: Error in =: 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: Curious, I'm trying to fix the issues in it. please check I fixed a plot. https://github.com/amrrs/google_trends_dashboard Btw, if the above answer has fixed that issue that you asked for, please mark the answer answere.d

Comment: Nice amrrs. Thanks a lot for you help. :)

Comment: Did you fix the bug with this error: Error in =: 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: I think yes, the first plot is displayed if you can see the repo

Comment: Yes the first plot is diplayes. The other plots returning this error.

Comment: Oh yeah, I actually didn't know what kind of plots where aimed there so didn't change. Need to change. Can you please raise an issue there with what kind of plots you expected in those?